# Stuck in GRUB after removing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

I need very specific help, how do I boot windows 8.1 when I am stuck in the GRUB "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported..."
I cannot boot from installation media as I have none and need help getting to Windows from inside GRUB.
Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? If UEFI go into UEFI boot tab and chose Windows. If BIOS you need a Windows repairCD or flash drive or maybe Boot-Repair installed into an Ubuntu live installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands on the grub command line

```
set root=(hd0,1)
chainloader +1
boot
```

You might need to use **ls** to ensure windows is in the (hd0,1) partition or not. If not, just enter the windows (or any other OS) partition instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I fixed this a while back by using chainloader (path to EFI boot loader) then boot (same path).